# How to get to Environment Variables from Run

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, run-dialog

I often need access to the Environment Variables on my Windows 7. What command do I need to type in the Run window to get to them?

At the moment I do the following:

Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>Start</kbd>, type `Path`, and click <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select `Edit environment variables for your account`.

I know its not strictly using `run` but it works and literally takes less than 2 sec.

Comment: I didn't know this can be done. You're right, much quicker! Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. The Start menu is surprisingly efficient for searching the control panel, just as it is surprisingly inefficient for searching files. :)

Comment: I never knew that, man that saves a lot of clicking thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Try using this: `"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

For more details check these links: [[1]](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/68086-open-the-environment-variable-editing-window/) and [[2]](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm).

Comment: on Windows 10, System Variables are read only. Edit button is disabled. You can edit the user Variables, though.

Comment: This is the correct answer... and should be accepted as the answer...

Comment: The "System Variables" are editable... you must launch the dialog as administrator though... is you wanna test just open a console as administrator... and use the command suggested by Mogana... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

You can shorten your path

- by doing `Run... -> "SystemPropertiesAdvanced"`
- or press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`

that will bring you two steps closer.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Run command

```
rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Open Like this
[image]